# Mnemonic tip for regex start of string/end of string metacharacters

Tags: regex, mnemonics

It is well known that regular expressions are powerful. But it is also known that the syntax is a bit awkward.

For example, each time I use them, I find asking myself which of `^` and `$` is the **start of string** (respectively **end of string**) metacharacter.

I know that a quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex%20metacharacter) or a simple [cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) may answer this, but yet I wonder if anyone knows a good mnemonic tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I can come up with: Starts small ends big.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a help for those anchors, but as long as you operate on the whole string and don't use the multi line modifier `m` (depends on your regex flavor) you can use in most flavors `\A` and `\z` (or `\Z`) for the same purpose.

Those are more intuitive to use, `A` us the start and `Z` is the end.

`\A` The beginning of the input
`\Z` The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
`\z` The end of the input

Answer (score 2):

`caret` comes before `dollar` alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I just had a talk about the exact same subject with people in various place on the internet. Here is what we found so far.

So, let’s begin with [a masonry analogy](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11152120). The caret (`^`) looks like a house roof. So let’s say that first you build the roof, then you get paid (got the `$`).

Similarly, [people mentioned](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11152122) that money always comes at the end, although some thought that it was not the case in some mafia business, so this is possibly a confusing mnemonic. [Variation](https://libranet.de/display/0b6b25a8-1564-5e8b-62d5-05c223076954) : *« you will be paid in the end »*.

A [simple, easy to remember one](https://social.linux.pizza/@vague/110355172867936609): *« `^` looks like a star(t) »*.

Comment: All the mnemonics come with links quoting the persoma you shared those brillant tricks. Thanks a lot to them!